# The dimension of splitting subbundles in the definition of a hyperbolic set.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

Let $f:M\rightarrow M$ be a diffeomorphism and $\Lambda$ be a hyperbolic set, where $M$ is a compact Riemannian manifold without boundary. In the definition of the hyperbolic set $\Lambda$, the tangent space over $\Lambda$ splits into two subbundles $T_{x}M=E_x^s\bigoplus E_x^u$ for all $x\in\Lambda$. Then there are conclusions that the dimensions of $E_x^s$ and $E_x^u$ are locally constant and those subspaces change conituously.

Thus, is it possible that the dimension of $E_x^s$(or $E_x^u$) changes as $x\in\Lambda$ varies ? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, in general the dimension may vary but it is locally constant, that is, in any arbitrarily small neighborhood of a given point in the hyperbolic set the dimensions of the stable and unstable spaces are constant in that neighborhood (precisely due to continuity, since the dimensions are integers). The compactness of $M$ does not interfere in any way.

As a consequence, you may simply take two fixed hyperbolic fixed points $p$ and $q$ of different stable (and unstable) dimension, and their union $\{p,q\}$ will be a hyperbolic set for which the stable and unstable spaces are not equal at every point.

Comment: According to your analysis above, it should be the case that the dimension of the splitting subbundle is constant on the component of the hyperbolic set, yes or no?

Comment: Yes, if you mean "on each connected component of the hyperbolic set".

Comment: However,  "on each invariant connected component of the hyperbolic set", is not always the case . For example, if we have a hyperbolic periodic orbit $\{p,f(p),....,f^ n (p)\}$  then each connected component is just a point on the orbit, but it is not invariant.